# Create a control object and return it from a function in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This function creates a control object of the TEdit type and returns it to whatever line in the code it happens to be called from:

```
function TBaseForm.CreateEdit(AOwner: TWinControl;
                              inTop, inLeft, inWidth: integer) : TEdit;
var
    edt: TEdit;
begin
    edt := TEdit.Create(AOwner);
    with edt do begin
        Parent := AOwner;
        Width  := inWidth;
        Top    := inTop;
        Left   := inLeft;
    end;
    result := edt;
end;
```

Later in the code:

```
edtTitle := CreateEdit(Self, 20, 90, 300);
```

Now. Are there not any problems with the code in the function? For example, Does anything not get hung somewhere in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no memory leak.

You can do it more cleanly (although I'm still not sure why you're doing this), and avoid the extra variable `edt`:

```
function TBaseForm.CreateEdit(AOwner: TWinControl;
                              inTop, inLeft, inWidth: integer) : TEdit;
begin
  Result := TEdit.Create(AOwner);
  Result.Parent := AOwner;
  Result.Width  := inWidth;
  Result.Top    := inTop;
  Result.Left   := inLeft;
end;
```

Comment: You should explain *why* there is no leak.